# Careers site, why no salary info - at least on the basic CV

Tags: discussion, jobs

Hi,

I have 85% completed my CV and I don't see any boxes on salaries, neither previous nor desired.

Any plans for this , or perhaps it comes up when you "file" your CV...?

I can see that you may not want to disclose precise figures, but a range might be useful, at least in the desired category, to see how compatible the employer/employee are...

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: No, I filed mine, and no mention of salary

Comment: Good question.  Recruiters especially use current salary to peg a valuation for you.  This will work _for you_ if you already have a high salary, but it will work against you if you are looking to jump into a job at a higher price (it looks like you're worth $75,000.. why should we pay $85,000?).  It's how their minds work.

Answer (score 12):

The advice I've had on this in the past, is to not state these figures -- they *can* put off employers that think they can't afford you (For example, a contractor who wants to take a pay cut to go perm); and you may get a lower salary offer than you'd get otherwise (as the employer know what you're after, they don't have to exceed your expectations)

Comment: +1 I've always been told to never discuss salary until you are at least past the first interview.

Answer (score 5):

For years I have publically published the hourly bill rate I am looking for as a contractor.

This is not a negotiating problem, because I am publishing the bill rate I want, not my prior bill rates.  I'm confident my rate is in the right ballpark as I've been contracting for quite a while and published both too low and too high rates over the years.

The primary reason I do this is to reduce spam.  I don't want to hear from potential employers who are not willing/interested in paying my desired bill rate.  It is a waste of my time.

You can publically publish your desired bill rate/salary on Careers by using one of the free form fields available to you.

The hard question for people who take my approach is: how do I know what I'm worth?  My answer is trial and error.  I also spend time talking to recruiters about what they are seeing for rates (always taking it with a grain of salt).  There are "ceilings", but they are not absolute and you can fight through them over time.